# translate .htaccess line to web.config for IIS

Tags: apache-http-server, iis

I have a PHP application hosted in `Linux Azure webapp`, and i would migrate from Apache to IIS (to `Windows Webapp` also).

I have these rules in my `.htaccess` file and i face some issue when trying to translate these rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . 
RewriteRule .* - [E=​HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}].
```

IIS import doesn't recognize these rules. so , how i can mitigate this problem ? Does IIS can support using .htaccess ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The file `.htaccess` is an Apache feature. IIS uses either global
in the `applicationHost.config` file or local in the `web.config`
file.
There is no direct translation of rules, since the concepts
of both products are very dissimilar.

For IIS you need to install
[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite),
and then you may create your rules.

Some useful references for getting you started:

- [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)
- [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)
- [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules - https, www, and more](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/)
- [Examples of my most useful IIS rewrite rules](https://www.yaplex.com/blog/examples-of-my-most-useful-iis-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Thanks for your Replay, i already install URL rewriter , but I'am unable to translate these two rules.

Comment: What do these rules do?

Comment: I use these rules to handle authorisation headers. In . htacess when i uncoment these lines , a error 401 not authorized is showing

Comment: But what exactly are they supposed to do?

Comment: In apache , these rules allow authorisation headers in PHP using post requests
So Can you please help me

Comment: On IIS this rule can [be ignored](https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/1-8-iis-rewrite-map-the-rule-cannot-be-converted-into-an-equivalent-iis-format-because-of-unsupported-flags-e/4247). Authorization info is passed in IIS as [AUTH_USER/AUTH_PASSWORD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)).

Comment: Can you please explain more ? I don't understand , how make this in web.config ?

Comment: Sorry , i don't have password , i have a generated token